# C# Multi Page WPF App, Height & Width of pages not the same

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create my first C# app and ran into a problem.

**MainWindow.xaml code below**

```
<NavigationWindow  x:Class="WPF_Navigation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Navigation"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350px" Width="525px" Source="incl/pages/Login.xaml">
```

**Login.xaml code below**

```
<Page x:Class="WPF_Navigation.incl.pages.Login"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Navigation.incl.pages"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Height="350px" Width="525px"
  Title="Login">

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="440,320,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see the height and width is exactly the same on both and the button is in the bottom right corner well within the 350px X 525px window. So why is it that when I run the app the button is out off screen? (had to resize window as seen in the image below)

[image: MainWindow Image]

Comment: Looking at the image again I believe it could be due to the Title and Navigation bars as MainWindow is a window and Login is a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows height includes all of its ui: your page + title + borders + ???. See this example

```xaml
<Window
  x:Name="TheWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Height="200">
  <Grid x:Name="TheGrid">  
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=TheGrid}" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

yields this:

[image]

So there is a difference of 39 pixels for the window ui (will vary depending on your os).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, thought that could be the issue.